# cookie in javascript restarts after each refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using this timer on each of my product pages: http://www.screencast.com/t/hsmzVOLBUJ
and example of product page URL: 
https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/collections/celtique/products/pendentif-chene-millenaire

It starts at 12hrs 4mn 26s and then decreases.
I would like it to be set with a cookie so that when the user navigates between different product pages, it keeps decreasing from the value of other pages ; and also if the user comes back in 12hrs, it displays 0hrs 4mn 26s.

So I am a bit unfamiliar with the integration of cookie in javascript, this would appear in the end of my code there:
`document.cookie = 'myClock='`

So far, the timer resets after each refresh

Do you have any idea to prevent that?
This would be a great help, thank you very much :)

```
<div id="clockdiv">
<span class="days"></span><div class="smalltext">jours</div>
<span class="hours"></span><div class="smalltext">hrs</div>
<span class="minutes"></span><div class="smalltext">mins</div>
<span class="seconds"></span><div class="smalltext">secs</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}
var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
if(document.cookie && document.cookie.match('myClock')){
  var deadline = document.cookie.match(/(^|;)myClock=([^;]+)/)[2];
}
else{
var timeInHours = 12;
var timeInMinutes = 4;
var timeInSeconds = 26;
var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInHours*60*60*1000 + timeInMinutes*60*1000 +  timeInSeconds*1000);
  document.cookie = 'myClock=' + deadline + '; path=/; domain= .https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
}
</script>
```

Comment: no idea for this issue?